Geometric alignment of adaptive models on evolving manifolds
Let $(M_t)_{t\in[0,T]}$ be a smooth family of compact $d$-dimensional Riemannian submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider a function $f_t : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ evolving over time $t \in [0,T]$ according to the gradient flow:
$$\frac{df_t}{dt} = -\nabla_\mathcal{H} L(f_t),$$
where $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space of functions, and $L(f_t)$ is the functional:
$$L(f_t) = \delta_{M_t}(f_t) + \lambda\|f_t\|_\mathcal{H}^2.$$
Here, $\delta_{M_t}(f_t)$ is the geometric misalignment metric:
$$\delta_{M_t}(f_t) = \int_{M_t} \|P_{T_x M_t} \nabla f_t(x) - \nabla_{M_t} f_t(x)\|^2 d\mu_t(x),$$
where $P_{T_x M_t}$ is the orthogonal projection onto the tangent space $T_x M_t$, $\nabla_{M_t}$ is the intrinsic gradient on $M_t$, and $\mu_t$ is the Riemannian volume measure on $M_t$.
Under what conditions on $(M_t)$ and $f_0$ does there exist a unique solution $f_t$ to this gradient flow for all $t \in [0,T]$? Does $\delta_{M_t}(f_t)$ converge to 0 as $t \to T$? If so, what is the rate of convergence, and how does it depend on the geometry of $(M_t)$ and properties of $f_0$? How does the smoothness of the family $(M_t)$ affect the regularity and convergence properties of $f_t$?
Any references or related research would be appreciated.
